# $DOCUMENTS installing to admin folder

Tags: windows, windows-7, nsis

I've got this nsis installer script. It is set to install to

```
InstallDir $DOCUMENTS\OCTGN\OCTGN
```

The problem is, the installer install .net 4.0 and vc2010, so it needs to be elevated to work. When it becomes elevated, if the user's account is 'Standard User', it will end up installing into the admin's My Documents folder instead.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this so it installs to the proper location?

As a side note:
I don't want to change to program files, app data, or any other location.

Comment: You really *should* change to App Data. The only thing that belongs in a user's "Documents" folder is stuff that the user puts there and *actual documents* that the user will manipulate. Your program's data does not belong there. Yes, Microsoft's programs sometimes get this wrong. That's no excuse for you not to follow the rules. It is a violation of the Windows interface guidelines for installers to dump crap in the Documents folder.

Comment: It wasn't a whim decision, there were many things that were considered before we decided the location. Thanks for the pep talk though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically fighting the way UAC is designed, the best option is to not mix writing to HKLM vs HKCU and $ProgramFiles vs $Profile.

A decent workaround would be to use `RequestExecutionLevel user` and if you detect that .net 4.0 or vc2010 are not installed then extract a mini installer that requests elevation and does the admin part of the setup.

Your final option is to use the [UAC plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in)...